# No grafica una consulta MySQL con chartjs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

estoy realizando una consulta de fechas para posteriormente graficarlas con chartjs pero si quiero realizar una consulta por ejemplo del 01-12-2021 al 03-12-2021 no me muestra nada aunque sí hay datos que cumplan esta condición pero si pongo del 01-12-2021 al 08-12-2021 si muestra datos y ahí aparecen los datos de la primera consulta, no sé qué está pasando, si me pudiera ayudar por favor

Formulario donde hago la consulta

```html
<form class="col-4 mt-5" action="" >
<div class="row">
<label class="col-12" for="">Fecha Inicial</label>
<input type="datetime" id="f1" required value='2021-12-01 00:00:00'">
<label class="col-12" for="">Fecha Final</label>
<input type="datetime" id="f2" required value='2021-12-15 23:59:59'">
```

Ajax donde mandó el archivo de las gráficas

```js
$('#Enviar').click(function(){
    var Fechain=document.getElementById('f1').value;
    var Fechafin=document.getElementById('f2').value;

    var ruta="Fein="+Fechain+"&Fefin="+Fechafin;

    $.ajax({
      url: 'pag/graf.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: ruta,
    })

    .done(function(res){
      $('#respuesta').html(res)
      //$('#f1').val('');
      //$('#f2').val('');
    })

    .fail(function(){
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function(){
      console.log("complete");
    })
});
```

Script donde imprimo los datos en la gráfica

```js
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("MiGrafica").getContext("2d");
    var container = document.getElementById('1');

    var chart = new Chart(ctx,{
        type: "bar",
        data:{
            labels:["Revisión de Anticipos y Facturas", "Liberación", "Reclamaciones", "Pedidos entregados"],
            datasets:[
                {
                labels: "Mi gráfica",
                backgroundColor: [ 'rgb(17, 169, 7)',
                                  'rgb(195, 3, 3)'],
                
                data: [
                    <?php echo dias($conexion,'FechaRegistro', 'FechaAdmin',$f1,$f2,'upedido','Admin')?>                       
                   
                ]
                },
            ]

        }
    
    }); 


</script>
```

Función PHP donde hago la consulta

```html
function dias($conexion,$FechaI,$FechaF,$f1,$f2, $tabla,$proc){
  //---------- Consultas ----------
  $query = "SELECT ".$FechaI.", ".$FechaF.", DATEDIFF(".$FechaF.", ".$FechaI.") from ".$tabla." WHERE ".$FechaI." BETWEEN '$f1' AND '$f2'";
  $festivo = "SELECT DFFecha from diasfest";
  $dia = "SELECT Proceso, Diastotal from uprocesos WHERE Proceso='$proc'";
  
  $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
  $resultado1 = $conexion->query($festivo);
  $resultado2 = $conexion->query($dia);
  
  //---------- Variables ----------
  $aux;
  $contador_dias = 0;
  $a_tiempo=0;

  /* Total Pedidos */
  if($resultado){
      $totalPedidos=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);  
      //echo intval($totalPedidos);
  }
  while($row2=$resultado2->fetch_assoc())
  {  
    $val = intval($row2['Diastotal']);
  }
  while($row1=$resultado1->fetch_assoc()){
  }
  while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc())
  {
      /* Si la fecha es default */
      $integer2 = intval($row['DATEDIFF('.$FechaF.', '.$FechaI.')']);

      for($i=0; $i<$integer2; $i++){    
          if( ($row[$FechaI] != $row1['DFFecha'])){   
              $aux = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row[$FechaI]."+ 1 days"));
              $row[$FechaI] = $aux;
              //echo " al ".date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row[$FechaI])).'<br>';
              if(date("w",strtotime($row[$FechaI])) != 0){
                  $contador_dias++;
              }       
          }else{
              $aux = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row[$FechaI]."+ 1 days"));
              $row[$FechaI] = $aux;
          }
      }
      if($contador_dias <= $val){
      $a_tiempo++;
      }  
      $contador_dias = 0;
  }
//echo $a_tiempo;
$val_final = ($a_tiempo*20)/$totalPedidos;

//echo $val_final;

return $val_final;


}
```

Comment: NO te funciona la consulta o la grafica?, si no te funciona la grafica solo provee los datos que estas trayendo

Comment: Hasta donde yo he hecho pruebas, tanto la consulta como la gráfica están bien, solo que no sé por qué cuando pongo rango de fechas cortos no me los muestra